Can't use cli angular cli command since v18 update
I try tο update my angular cli version as usual for test it, but since I did this update I have a node error when I try to use cli command.
All of my other global dependencies seem to work.
I try to downgrade angualr cli version, node version, remove them and reinstall them but it doesn't work.
The error is the following:

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1148 throw err; ^ Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Xavie\node_modules@angular\cli\bin\ng.js' at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1145:15) at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:986:27) at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:174:12) at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49 { code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND', requireStack: [] }


Can you share the error you are getting?

yes this is the erro i get: node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1148
throw err;
^
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Xavie\node_modules@angular\cli\bin\ng.js'
at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1145:15)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:986:27)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:174:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49 {
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
requireStack: []
}

did you try like said here? npm remove -g @angular/cli npm install -g @angular/cli  (after you are sure you have the new node version correctly installed)

Yes i try it and i also try to restart my computer between each step

Update
I find the problems it seems that bun also has @angular/cli installed globally and it's provide conflict with npm dependencies
